# how to have a unique student Id

Tags: java, arrays, methods, random, bluej

The problem is that I cant create a unique Student number, Sometimes I get the same student Id when i store a student, is there anyway of generating unique studentID numbers, I need to amend the store method so its creating a unique

```
public class Collection

{

   private ArrayList<Student> studentList;


    public Collection()
    {
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public void storeStudent(Student student)
    {

        student.setId(createId("AB",9));
        studentList.add(student);

    }
     public String createId(String pre, int number)
     {
         Random random = new Random();
          int index = random.nextInt(number);
          return pre + index + " ";
     }
}


public class Student

{
private String studentId;

private String name;


public Student( String name)
{
    studentId = "UnKnow";
    this.name = name;
}
public void setId(String id)
{
    studentId = id;
}
}
```

Comment: How about incrementing a counter which you save alongside the data?

Comment: Ghassar, it is *not* acceptable if you continue to reask questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599427/generating-unique-student-id-numbers and trying to make users here to do your work ! -1.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a UUID:

```
public String createId() //don't need the arguments any more
{
     UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
     return uuid.toString();
}
```

Extremely unlikely to ever have a clash.

Comment: `Extremely unlikely to ever have a clash.` Yes, and that's the problem. If you want something unique, *check that it is really unique*.

Comment: The annual risk of being hit by a meteorite is approximately equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate. Not a concern which is forefront in most people's minds.

Comment: Done right "Extremely unlikely" means "Less likely than an asteroid obliterating the earth in the next half hour". Or less likely than an originally unique short id becoming unique due to in memory flipping of bits by cosmic radiation.

Comment: Furthermore, the solutions involving incrementing integers - the int would probably overflow before a UUID clash.

Answer (score 2):

make the studentId variable static and create static method to generate studentId.

```
private static studentId = 0;
...
public static int generateStudentId()
{
return studentId++;
}
```

you might also want to store this value to db or file or whatsoever, in case you stop the app and relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static final AtomicInteger idIncrement = new AtomicInteger();
 public static String createId(String pre /*, int number -- no longer needed*/)
 {
      int index = idIncrement.incrementAndGet();
      return pre + index + " ";
 }
```

This would give you thread-safe unique ordered student ids.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class Collection {
    static long id = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public void storeStudent(Student student) {
        student.setId(++id + "");
        studentList.add(student);
    }
```

It guarantees unique IDs even after you restart the app. Note that it is not thread safe, if you need it to be thread-safe use AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Set in collections. It will not allow duplicates. Also you can easily convert Set into List as follows.

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(set);
```

Brief tutorial on [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Hope this will helpful to you.

Thanks you.